# How can i put my searchbox and navbar at the same line?

Tags: css, navbar

I'm trying to make my search box in the same line with the "home, about, contact..." stuff but it doesn't seem to worrk, i guess my CSS just not enough to make that, can anyone help me to make them stand in the same line? Thank you so much!

This is css:

```
.container{

    background-color: #A3318A;
}

.container ul{
    display: inline block;

}

.container ul li {
    
    display: inline;
    padding:15px;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: white;

}
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/48a972c999.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>News</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
        <form>
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Search here...">
            <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: my image]

Comment: You'll need to make the form `inline-block`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `form` with `display: inline-block`:

```
.container form, /* added */
.container ul{
  display: inline-block; /* fixed */
}
```